# How to prevent App-wide search with Searchable Plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

For my Grails App i use Searchable Plugin to have an nice "google-like" Search.

I followed instructions and added:

```
class Address {
    static searchable =true

    Integer id                  
    AddressGroups addressType   
    String briefDescription     
    String company 
}
```

It really works fine.
The Problem here is that the Searchbar in my App is searching through all Classes.

I know it is a simple Problem. But i found no Documentation for that issue. I just want to search one domain class at time. Not all classes.

**More Information:**
Additionally i got an User Class and an AddressGroups Class.
As you can see Addressgroups provides addressType for Address.

Comment: can you provide more information? What other classes? I believe that by default the plugin will include domain objects included in the association you have created

Comment: Added addtional Info...hmm sounds interessting. How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to only search for results of one type you can add an additional search term "alias:DomainClassName" (this has to be anded to the normal query)
so it becomes

(searchterm) AND (alias:DomainClassName)

if you want the Person as a result if the term is found in the addressGroups you could define addressGroups as a component and make the addressgroups a non-root object for compass.

```
class Person {
    AdressGroups addressType
    static searchable = {
        root true
        addressType component: [prefix:'person_']
    }
}
class AdressGroups {
    static searchable = {
        root false
    }
}
```